# Create a Thread in UEFI

Tags: c, multithreading, uefi

Is there a way to have a threaded application running on UEFI? I've only found a few mentions of threading in the UEFI specifications, but they didn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no threads in UEFI right now, but there is a [MpService protocol](http://wiki.phoenix.com/wiki/index.php/EFI_MP_SERVICES_PROTOCOL), that can be used for performing tasks on CPU cores other then BSP (BootStrap Processor, the core that runs UEFI itself).
You can read more about the same question [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/edk2-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00130.html), nearly nothing is changed from that time. [This presentation](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/Plugfest_Multiprocessing-with_UEFI-McDaniel.pdf) can also be useful, but not all functions mentioned there (sync primitives library, for example) are implemented in any given UEFI firmware.